# Pandas ImportError: C extension: No module named 'pandas._libs' not built

Tags: python, pandas, importerror

I am getting a persistent error from Pandas:

```
In [3]: import pandas
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\swan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>()
     25 try:
---> 26     from pandas._libs import (hashtable as _hashtable,
     27                              lib as _lib,

ImportError: No module named 'pandas._libs'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d6ac987968b6> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas

C:\Users\swan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>()
     33                       "pandas from the source directory, you may need to run "
     34                       "'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build "
---> 35                       "the C extensions first.".format(module))
     36
     37 from datetime import datetime

ImportError: C extension: No module named 'pandas._libs' not built. If you want to import pandas from the source dir
ectory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Pandas using `pip`, but to no avail.  Can someone tell me how to fix this?

---

EDIT: In response to a request to try `pip install --force-reinstall pandas`, here's what I got:

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install --force-reinstall pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-0.24.2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl (8.5 MB)
Collecting numpy>=1.12.0
  Using cached numpy-1.18.4-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl (12.7 MB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.5.0
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Collecting pytz>=2011k
  Downloading pytz-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 510 kB 50 kB/s
Collecting six>=1.5
  Downloading six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Installing collected packages: numpy, six, python-dateutil, pytz, pandas
  Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.18.4
    Uninstalling numpy-1.18.4:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.18.4
  Attempting uninstall: six
    Found existing installation: six 1.10.0
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'six'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which fil
es belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Comment: What happens when you `pip install --force-reinstall pandas`?

Comment: @r.ook I've edited the post to show what happens in that case.

Comment: In that case, try `pip install --force--reinstall pandas --ignore-installed six`.  It sounds like something went awry when you installed `pandas`.  Hopefully a reinstall works, if not, I'm not too sure.

Comment: @r.ook this was my solution! To make it work, I had to go through the anaconda navigator and install the CMD.exe prompt so that I could modify my environment. I then used your command there and it worked! Thank you, I was dealing with that issue for hours

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it as the following :

- Uninstall pandas "pip uninstall pandas"
- download the source from https://pypi.org/project/pandas/#modal-close
- Open a terminal/command prompt in the folder
- run "python setup.py build_ext --force"
- run "python setup.py install"

There you go.